# Microsoft Word: apply style to HTML tags with a given class

Tags: microsoft-word, html, styles

I have an HTML document I am importing into Microsoft Word for the further processing. Some paragraphs in my HTML document are formatted with a class from the linked CSS, for example:

```html
<p class="section_title">Section title</p>
```

I'd like to create a dedicated Microsoft Word style for all these tags with a given class to have the ability to format them easily by changing the properties of the style.

Is there a way to do that manually or with VBA? I am even ready to change the source of the HTML before opening it in Word if there is a rule MS Word uses to link HTML tags to existing styles or create new ones (for example, use class names starting with 'Mso' like 'MsoNormal' and the like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, I have found an answer myself. At least, for paragraph styles. We just need to define the given paragraph style in the CSS using the `tag`.`class` format, for example:

```css
p.section_title
{
    margin: 0.9em 0em 0.6em 0em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

When I open an HTML with such CSS formatting in Word, the style list contains the `section_title` style I can use like any normal Word style.